# How tables in Settings.app are implemented?

Tags: ios, swift

I need similar interface(as Settings has) in my app. Do not want to re-inventing the wheel and wondering are these two UITableViews or one with two sections? How implemented label("Double tapping...") under the neath then?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic grouped table with section headers and footers. Both header and footer are using their default appearance.

This is what you get when you return header and footer from data source methods:

```
func table​View(UITable​View, title​For​Header​In​Section:​ Int)
```

and

```
func table​View(UITable​View, title​For​Footer​In​Section:​ Int)
```

Comment: Event didn't know about footers :) Thank you.